# Polar divisor contains no hyperplane when degree $d\geq 3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, projective-geometry, deformation-theory

Let $X\subset \mathbb P^n=\mathbb P^n_\mathbb C$ $(n>3)$ be a smooth hypersurface of degree $d\geq 3$, defined by a homogeneous polynomial $F$. Let $a=[a_0:\ldots:a_n]\in \mathbb P^n$ be any closed point, then the corresponding **polar divisor** with **pole** $a$ is defined to be the zero locus of $\sum a_i \partial_iF=0$ in $\mathbb P^n$. I believe the following statement is always true but I did not find how to prove:

> there is no polar divisor contains a hyperplane in $\mathbb P^n$.

There is a very geometric interpretation: if a hyperplane contains in some polar divisor, then the nearby hyperplane sections of $X$ are all isomorphic. This phenomenon should not occur when degree is at least $3$. (In the case of degree $2$, a polar divisor is always a hyperplane, which should be interpreted as all smooth quadratic surfaces are isomorphic. This is also the classic [pole and polar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_and_polar).)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $X\subset \mathbb P^3$ be the cubic surface defined by $x^3+y^3+z^3+w^3$, and let $a=[1:0:0:0]$. Then the corresponding polar divisor is the zero locus of $x^2$, and thus contains a hyperplane. What is true is that a *general* polar divisor will not contain a hyperplane (in characteristic 0 at least).